Potential function of a flow around a stagnation point
Following the Steve Brunton lecture about the potential flow. It is possible de find the potential function by solving the Laplace's equation. In his first example (the same as the following picture) it seems impossible to find the potential functions by solving the Laplace equation in cartesian coordinates.
The solution for the Laplace's equation $\Delta \phi = 0$ in 2d is:
$$\phi(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$$
$$\Delta\phi = \frac{\partial^2 X(x)Y(y)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 X(x)Y(y)}{\partial y^2} = \frac{Y(y)\partial^2 X(x)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{X(x)\partial^2 Y(y)}{\partial y^2} = 0$$
$$\Delta\phi = \frac{\partial^2 X(x)}{X(x)\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 Y(y)}{Y(y)\partial y^2} = 0 $$
Hence, $$\frac{\partial^2 X(x)}{X(x)\partial x^2} = C$$ and $$\frac{\partial^2 Y(y)}{Y(y)\partial y^2} = -C$$
The solutions for the $x$ equation is $$\sum_m (A_m e^{mx} + B_m e^{-mx})$$ and for $y$ $$\sum_m (C_m sin(my) + D_m cos (my))$$
The general solution is then:
$$\phi = \sum_m (A_m e^{mx} + B_m e^{-mx}) (C_m sin(my) + D_m cos (my))$$
From the scheme, far from the stagnation ($y = y_0 >> 1$) point at $x=0$ the velocity must be constant in $-y$ direction. Hence, the velocity could be something like $\vec{u} = -u_0 \hat{y}$  far from the stagnation point.
Also, knowing that
$$\vec{u} = \nabla \phi$$
$$\phi = -u_0 y$$
far from the stagnation point.
Hence,
$$\sum_m (A_m e^{mx} + B_m e^{-mx}) (C_m sin(my) + D_m cos (my)) = -u_0 y$$
far from the stagnation point.
For my understanding, the equality above seems impossible, why?
Scheme of the problem

Can you please give the domain and boundary conditions and how they relate to the stagnation point? It is difficult to answer your question since we have no notion of how the stagnation point relates to the solution without scrubbing through an hour long lecture

@whpowell96 The boundary conditions are $\vec{u} = -u_0 \hat{y}$ far from the stagnation point and also $\frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial y} = 0$ at the "plane", since the flow can't pass through the solid plane. I'm not sure about the domain. Neither wikipedia or the lecture mention the domain.

How did you arrive at this solution? This solution corresponds to a specific domain and set of boundary conditions which may or may not correspond to your problem

I found the solution of the Laplace's equation in cartesian coordinates using the separation of variable method. I didn't use the boundary conditions yet. Also, according to linkWikipedia, the solution should be in the form of $2K(x^2 - y^2)
$

How did you apply separation of variables without knowing the domain? Please add more details to clarify the specific problem you are trying to solve.

I might missed something. I'm not sure to understand exactly what details you need.
As I said I was following few lectures and to find the potential function I have to solve the Laplace's equation. I only replaced $\phi(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$ and then plugged it in the Laplace's equation. I'll add the full details in my post, but I'm not sure exactly how it could help.
